# How to list the data in the tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is the screen shot. According to this how to list the data in the tableview:

[image]

Already I have code as below.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return questionViewModel.numberOfSections()
     }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
     } func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let identifier = "HeaderCell"
       var headercell: questionheader! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? questionheader
        if headercell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "questionheader", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            headercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_questionheader
        }     headercell.setReviewData(reviews:questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:section))
            headercell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return headercell

    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return questionViewModel.numberOfRowsIn(section: section)
     }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let model = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
        print(model.answerType)
       print(model.answerType?.rawValue)
        let c = model.answerType
        return c!.cellType().getHeight()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let model = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
            print(model.answerType)
            print(model.answerType?.rawValue)
            let c = model.answerType
            let cellClass = c?.cellType().getClass()
            print(cellClass)
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: (cellClass?.cellReuseIdentifier())!, for: indexPath) as! BaseCell
            print(cell)
         cell.selectionStyle = .none
 let optionModel = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
          cell.setOptions(Options1: optionModel)
         cell.delegate = self
        if optionModel.isSelected!
                    {
                    print(optionModel.isSelected)
                    cell.setOptions1(OptionsSelected:optionModel)
        }
         else {
                    print(optionModel.isSelected)
                    cell.setOptions1(OptionsisSelected:optionModel)
         }
        cell.type = c?.cellType()
         print(cell.type)
       else if cell.type == .radiotype{
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
        }
       return cell
   }
```

This is my code. But according to this I will get the output as below screen shot.

[image: This is the screen shot]

Actually initially I need to display the section header as: - Please tell about us

After that there is subsection. The subsection questions header are as below: -1. knowledge 2. friendly or not

Then in the subsections display the options. How to do implement?

Comment: how to implement this?

Comment: What you did so far to achieve this

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich i have added my code please check .And how  to implement?

Comment: Please reformat the code and remove the many unnecessary empty lines.

Comment: @vadian i have edited .And how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Below example may help you out.

```
  let sections = [ // All sections
        [ // Sports section
            ["Baseball", "Softball", "Cricket"], // Bat-and-Ball sub-section
            ["Field Hockey", "Ice Hockey", "Roller Hockey"] // Hockey subsection
        ], [ // Engineering section
            ["Software Engineer", "Electrical Engineer"] // Computer Science subsection
        ]
    ]


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let sectionItems = sections[section]
        var numberOfRows: Int = sectionItems.count // For second level section headers
        for rowItems: [Any] in sectionItems as? [[Any]] ?? [] {
            numberOfRows += rowItems.count // For actual table rows
        }
        return numberOfRows
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var sectionItems = sections[indexPath.section]
        var sectionHeaders = self.sectionHeaders[indexPath.section]
        let itemAndSubsectionIndex: IndexPath? = computeItemAndSubsectionIndex(for: indexPath)
        let subsectionIndex = Int(itemAndSubsectionIndex?.section ?? 0)
        let itemIndex: Int? = itemAndSubsectionIndex?.row

        if (itemIndex ?? 0) < 0 {
            // Section header
            let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SECTION_HEADER_CELL", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = sectionHeaders[subsectionIndex] as? String
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ROW_CONTENT_CELL", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = sectionItems[subsectionIndex][itemIndex ?? 0] as? String
            return cell
        }
    }
    func computeItemAndSubsectionIndex(for indexPath: IndexPath?) -> IndexPath? {
        var sectionItems = sections[Int(indexPath?.section ?? 0)]
        var itemIndex: Int? = indexPath?.row
        var subsectionIndex: Int = 0
        for i in 0..<sectionItems.count {
            // First row for each section item is header
            itemIndex = (itemIndex ?? 0) - 1
            // Check if the item index is within this subsection's items
            let subsectionItems = sectionItems[i] as? [Any]
            if (itemIndex ?? 0) < Int(subsectionItems?.count ?? 0) {
                subsectionIndex = i
                break
            } else {
                itemIndex = itemIndex! - (subsectionItems?.count)!
            }
        }
        return IndexPath(row: itemIndex ?? 0, section: subsectionIndex)
    }
```

And for objective-C Help you may following URL 
http://sapandiwakar.in/nested-sections-in-uitableview/

Comment: is there any mistake in the code:- let sections = [ // All sections
        [ // Sports section
            [Baseball, Softball, Cricket], // Bat-and-Ball sub-section
            [Field Hockey, Ice Hockey, Roller Hockey] // Hockey subsection
        ], [ // Engineering section
            [Software Engineer, Electrical Engineer] // Computer Science subsection
        ]
    ]    ,there showing error.How to solve and where needed to paste this code.

Comment: give me a minute

Comment: but you need to create section headers array by yourself too.

Comment: but still error in the code:- for rowItems: [Any] in sectionItems as? [[Any]] ?? [] {
            numberOfRows += rowItems.count // For actual table rows
        }
Here in sectionItems showing error as '[Any]' is not a subtype of Array<String>

Comment: And also error in the cell for row at:- var sectionItems = sections[indexPath.section]
        var sectionHeaders = self.sectionHeaders[indexPath.section]    here showing as error:-value of type has no member in sectionHeader.How to solve?

Comment: you to tell the section i have left it for you so that you can learn ... how to use. This is not a code writing portal its just a helping portal.

Comment: how you can write the code when you even don't know how to fix type casting issues and declare some array ?

Comment: i am new in this field.I am learning to fix the each issues.Thank u your best service .But one think for a beginner each bugs will improve to solve the issues.If there is no doubt in code,then there is no need to post the question for the help.Thank u ...

Answer (score 0):

You can just display "Please tell us about" as `UILabel` above the table.

Comment: how to use nested section?

Comment: You don't need nested section. Just a label with the text and table with options.